# How to set up a Tab Bar iOS app with UITableViews?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbar

I am attempting to create a 3 tab iPhone Application with UITableViews on 2 of the tabs.  I think I remember reading somewhere in Apple's documentation that it's not kosher to put navigation controllers like the one supplied in the navigation template on a tab bar App.  However, this is precisely what I am attempting to do and I wanted to know how I would go about doing it?

I started with the tab bar template and simply added this to the firstView header:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

I added a UITableView through IB and set the delegate and datasource to the FirstViewController's File Owner, but for some reason, I am not seeing tableView when I try to set it as the outlet from File Owner.  It makes me think that I am possibly going about this the wrong way.  Any advice at all would be greatly appreciated.

I am fairly new to programming overall, so please try to be clear.

Comment: If your view controllers serve only to manage table views, Apple supplies the `UITableViewController` class for that purpose without the need to create an outlet `UITableView`. You can have a tab bar controller that manages `UITableViewController` subclasses.

Comment: There is a lot in this question. Firstly Apple's iPod App has nav controllers in a tab bar App so I doubt your first statement is completely true. The easiest way is to what BoltClock. I don't think your going to get a clear precise answer. Also how to add a nav controller through a tab bar is another question in itself.

Comment: I found a spot in IB where I can set the class of each tab so I set the first tab to UITableViewController.  Then I went into the header file and set it to UITableViewController as well and now a UITableView comes up, but it is not populating in the same way other UITableViews that I have built populate? (To Rudiger - I actually think that adding NavControllers to the TabController would work perfectly!!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach it, from the nib, results in a structure looks like this:

Tab Bar Controller

-Tab Bar

--Navigation Controller

---Navigation Bar

---View Controller 1

---Tab Bar Item

--Navigation Controller

---Navigation Bar

---View Controller 2

---Tab Bar Item

...etc